# Oracle: WHERE ID IN () single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2...
FROM VIEW1
WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TABLE1 WHERE NAME_FIELD LIKE '%ABC%')
ORDER BY FIELD1, FIELD2;
```

When select from a view, one of the condition is this WHERE ID IN (subquery). The oracle error as in title is raised.

But if I ran the subquery first, then replace the subquery with the returned IDs, it is working.

Or if I attached the subquery inside of the view query, it is also working.

What have I done wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: What if you try `select * from VIEW1`?

Comment: Thank you @Aleksej, I have spotted the problem. It's a sub-query within the view. A data quality issue.

Comment: When you check for an IN condition, select DISTINCT doesn't help - rather, it hurts. select DISTINCT is much more expensive than simple SELECT. Try it both ways and see which works better.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cut operation instead:

```
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2...
  FROM VIEW1
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                 FROM TABLE1 
                WHERE NAME_FIELD LIKE '%ABC%' 
                  AND VIEW1.ID = TABLE1.ID)
ORDER BY FIELD1, FIELD2;
```